# How to create dynamic, protected routes for next.js middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have created a file, routes.ts that stores routes I would like to protect. This works for regular routes, such as my '/profile' route, but when I try to add a dynamic url, it does not work (a user that is not authenticated can still view these routes).

routes.ts

```
export const protectedRoutes = ["/profile", "/profile/[id]", "/timeline/[id]", "/"];
export const authRoutes = ["/login"];
export const publicRoutes = [];
```

middleware.ts

````
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const currentUser = request.cookies.get("currentUser")?.value;

  if (
    protectedRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname) &&
    (!currentUser || Date.now() > JSON.parse(currentUser).expiredAt)
  ) {
    request.cookies.delete("currentUser");
    const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url));
    response.cookies.delete("currentUser");

    return response;
  }

  if (authRoutes.includes(request.nextUrl.pathname) && currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/profile", request.url));
  }
}```



I have logged out of my application and tried to view the dynamic routes. If my code was correct, I should have been rerouted to my login page, however, it still shows the data even though I am not authenticated. To make sure the protected routes work, I viewed my static routes, and was successfully rerouted to the login page.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a `config` variable in the middleware and apply the middleware on the routes you want to protect. For example you can add this to the `middleware` for the dynamic routes:

```
export const config = {
    matcher: ["/profile/:path*", "/timeline/:path*"]
};
```

Please note if include the `config` in your middleware, the middleware will ONLY be applied to the routes in the `matcher` array. I just added the above code for the dynamic routes you had as an example.

The `matcher` is an array of routes to apply the middleware on. It supports the wildcard syntax so you can match a group of routes for the dynamic routes. For example, the `/profile/:path*` part will Apply the middleware on all the routes that starts with `/profile`. It will match the routes like `/profile/123`. Read more about `config` and `matcher` [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).